# What is a word that means something which another thing is imported into?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, if I import goods into Botswana, then the goods are importees, I am an importer, and Botswana is the... ?

Does such a word exist?

My curiosity has been aroused because I am coding a thing that does data importing, and having to say "site which you are importing into" is making my code comments hellishly long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

recipient

*noun*

> A person or thing that receives or is awarded something.

*adjective*

> Receiving or capable of receiving something.
>   ‘a recipient country’

([Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/recipient))

Comment: You rock! I can't believe I didn't think of this.

Comment: Also in the case of [organ transplantation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organ_transplantation), we talk about _recipient_ (and donor).